# Getting access token from Web Api using credentials of MVC Local user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I have an MVC application built that uses forms authentication and stores credentials encrypted in AspNetUsers

I also have a web api application that using that same store of users and is secured with oAuth.

The api is tested and works from an javascript app (going to be deployed on smartphones).

Now I also have a need to access the same API from the MVC app.  Basically the user is already logged in an authenticated, but as far as I can see, in order to get an access token from the API (calling the api/token endpoint) I need the users password, which is one way encrypted in the DB.

The API and MVC app are deployed as two separate apps.

I guess one way I could do this is to grab the access_token when they first log into the MVC app and store it in the user table.

Is there a another recommended way to handle this in the .NET world?

Thanks